# ldf excessive resource usage

Tags: cpanel, whm

I'm having issues with my WHM server. I'm receiving messages indicating that a Perl process is consuming a lot of time. Here are two examples of messages I receive:

```
Time:         Tue May  2 19:32:22 2023 +0200
Account:      [account_name]
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     1491319 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/536/bin/perl
Command Line: ubic-guardian ubic-periodic --rotate-logs --period=60 --stdout=/home2/[account_name]/ubic/log/watchdog.log --stderr=/home2/[account_name]/ubic/log/watchdog.err.log ubic-watchdog
PID:          2546 (Parent PID:2546)
Killed:       No
```

```
Time:         Tue May  2 19:32:22 2023 +0200
Account:      [account_name]
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     1491319 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/536/bin/perl
Command Line: /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/536/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/536/bin/ubic-periodic --rotate-logs --period=60 --stdout=/home2/[account_name]/ubic/log/watchdog.log --stderr=/home2/[account_name]/ubic/log/watchdog.err.log ubic-watchdog
PID:          2547 (Parent PID:2546)
Killed:       No
```

There is no useful information in the log files mentioned in the messages. Can anyone help me understand what is causing this issue and how to fix it? I appreciate any assistance.